# Add Integer into existing list

Tags: python, list, integer

I have list like :

```
a=['2345']
```

I want to add new integer to my list:

```
b=435
```

How can I have a new list which looks like :

```
new_list=['2345','434']
```

I have tried so many ways but sometimes it looks like :

```
['2345',434]
```

while the new data "434" does not have the quotation mark inside the list!
I have tried to convert the integer to string, then to the list, but it got worst!

Comment: *I have tried to convert the integer to string, then to the list, but it got worst!* what happened exactly as this is exactly what should work?

Comment: it looked like : ['2345','4','3','4'] !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the first item on your list is a string, not an integer:

```
>>> a=['2345']
>>> type(a[0])
<type 'str'>
```

If you want to add the integer as a string, you can use `str`:

```
>>> b=435
>>> a+[str(b)]
['2345', '435']
```

or

```
>>> a.append(str(b))
>>> a
['2345', '435']
```

Answer (score 2):

a=['2345']

b=435

a.append(b)

a = map(str, a)

print a

---Output

['2345', '435']

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=['2345']
>>> b = 435
>>> a + [str(b)]
['2345', '435']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ['2345']
>>> b = 435
>>> new_list = a + [str(b)]
>>> new_list
['2345', '435']
```